# How to bind the Super key in Emacs (non Windows)

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows

Running

```
xev | awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8 }'
```

results in

**133 Super_L**

when pressing my Windows key (there is only one). How do I make use of this in Emacs if I want to bind this key to a function?

Comment: What does Emacs tell you if you do `C-h c` and then press the Super key? If it tells you nothing, Emacs does not see it (it is probably hijacked by your desktop environment) then you cannot bind it. That is *NOT* an Emacs problem. I'm pretty sure I told you all this before in another (very similar if not identical) question.

Comment: Emacs doesn't see it, but I can use the key in LXTerminal, and xev identifies it as 133 Super_L

Comment: It may be that Emacs sees the <super> key but as a modifier (like <shift>, <control> or <meta>), so maybe you can bind something like `s-s` (i.e. hold down <super> and press the `s` key) but not the modifier key alone. Try `C-h c s-s` and see what Emacs says for that.